# Basic toggle() bottom-to-top slide issue

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-animate

This code actually works, but not exactly in the way I'm expecting.

".socialSlide" is a div set at the bottom of the page that features an anchor "tab" that sticks out. The rest of the div is hidden at the bottom. The idea is to have the div show or hide via animation either on click or hover of that link.

```
// Adding the anchor link and hiding the rest of the div   
$('.socialSlide').prepend('<a href="#" class="ssOpen">Share</a>').css('bottom', '-77px');
```

And adding the toggle function to that anchor

```
    /*add socialSlide toggle*/
$('.socialSlide a.ssOpen').toggle(function() {
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({"bottom": "-25px"},{ queue:false, duration:900, easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
    }, function() {     
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({"bottom": "70px"},{ queue:false, duration:900, easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
```

What is happening:

1. The anchor receives the first
   animate command on click. Fine.
2. Another click on the anchor link should
   hide back the div as before, but it
   doesn't happen. It goes up at least
   other 70 px.
3. A third click on the
   anchor seems to execute the second
   function() correctly, and then the
   first, from there on.

So, what may be happening on step 2? Am I missing something? Apologies if this sounds too basic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show this in action - either your own site or on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

The second step should hide the div? then bottom should have negative value:

```
$('.socialSlide a.ssOpen').toggle(function() {
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({"bottom": "-25px"},{ queue:false, duration:900});
}, function() {     
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({"bottom": "-70px"},{ queue:false, duration:900});
});
```

But I won't use this to hide show items, instead wrap the content with another DIV and slideToggle it, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/h4ZjS/4/).